# Quão importante é usar URL amigável?

Tags: url, ux, gui

Por exemplo:

```
meusite.com.br/posts/isto-e-um-slug-de-um-post
```

em vez de

```
meusite.com.br/posts/295837
```

- No primeiro caso a URL fica bem mais amigável, porém existe um custo de tempo pra desenvolver e dar manutenção em algo assim.
- No segundo caso a URL é pouco amigável mas dá "zero" trabalho porque é o comportamento *default* dos *frameworks web*.

Minha dúvida é se vale a pena investir tempo em algo assim, que eventualmente o usuário pode nem notar.

Comment: `porém existe um custo de tempo pra desenvolver e dar manutenção em algo assim.` Se você está a desenvolver isso, você está a reinventar a roda.

Comment: Outra coisa: dá uma olhada na URL desta própria pergunta. Acredito que lá você encontrará a melhor resposta ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A URL amigável é importante nestes casos:

## Melhor visualização ao usuário

Não só da URL na aba do navegador enquanto o usuário navega, mas caso ele favorite a página, compartilhe com seus colegas através de mensagens, eles saberão do que se trata talvez antes mesmo de abrir a página.

## Indexação de motores de busca

É mais provável um motor de busca localizar o post da página utilizando a URL como referência. Exemplo: ao procurar por stackoverflow os motores de busca identificam rapidamente a URL em questão, ao procurar por uma pergunta (que você sabe que existe neste site), você rapidamente vai encontrar pelo título que é definido tanto na URL como na tag  e também como h1 (você pode ver nesta página por exemplo), é uma referência adicional e importante.

## Confiança

O usuário experiente analisa o link antes de clicá-lo. Perceba que até você ja ficou inseguro com links encurtados como "http://shorturl.com?fw=oihf843kf90". Quando você visualiza um título ou algo do gênero, sua confiança aumenta: http://www.conversion.com.br/otimizacao-de-sites-seo/

## Segurança

Pode ter uma proteção a mais, pois você não estará deixando seus arquivos expostos do tipo: 'www.exemplocompras.com.br/produtos.php?id=32', que necessariamente uma busca para melhor aproveitamento do usuário e para a distribuição da informação você terá que passar os parâmetros por "GET".

Comment: Aceito sugestões para melhorar a resposta

Answer (score 3):

Alguns pontos que considero importantes e relevantes para o uso de url amigável

#### Raking em sites de busca

Motores de sites de buscas tratam url dinâmica *(minha-pagina.php?post=1234)* diferente de url estática *(minha-pagina/post/url-amigavel)*, portanto pode ajudar melhorar o ranking da página.

#### Descrição de conteúdo

Ao ler uma url amigável *(stackoverflow/quao-importante-e-usar-url-amigavel)* o usuário já sabe o que vai encontrar na página de destino antes mesmo de clicar, diferentemente de ler *(stackoverflow/21943)*, mas note que neste caso, para facilitar a implementação pode-se usar *(stackoverflow/21943/quao-importante-e-usar-url-amigavel)*

#### Memorização

Usuários podem memorizar mais facilmente uma url *(minha-pagina/marca/produto)* do que *(minha-pagina/1234/3887929)*, neste caso uma frase pode se tornar uma url *(esportes/copa-do-mundo-2014/gols-da-rodada)*, isto facilita o usuário chegar diretamente a página desejada e ainda entender o conteúdo da página de destino.

#### Divulgação

Uma url amigável torna-se mais fácil de ser divulgada, seja por telefone, banner, folder, cartão e etc...